# Set the CRS in the output file using gdal translate

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-translate

I am trying to stack the single band image into a composite band. I am able to do the stack the bands but the crs is not set.Also when i use the outputSRS in my code the code runs but the image is not created and if i leave it out the stacking is done but no crs is set

```
import rasterio
import os
import gdal
file_list = []
path = "M:\\sentinel\\tiff\\"
file_path = os.listdir(path)
cp_meta = rasterio.open(path + file_path[0])
meta = cp_meta.meta
meta.update(count = len(file_list))
for file in file_path:
    file = os.path.join(path,file)
    file_list.append(file)

meta.update(count = len(file_list))


save_path = "M:\\sentinel\\stack\\stack.tif"
outvrt = './stacked.vrt'
outds = gdal.BuildVRT(outvrt, file_list,xRes=10,yRes=10,separate=True)
outds = gdal.Translate(save_path,outds,format = "GTiff",creationOptions['TILED:YES'],outputSRS="EPSG:32633" )
```

i dont want to create another file using gdal.Warp just to set the crs.In the documentation for gdal translateoptions this is the correct way, but i dont know why its not working

Comment: See examples about how to use "options" in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_translate_lib.py

Comment: Did you close or delete the `outds` handle?

Comment: `cp_meta` also needs to be closed

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some time ago when assigning crs with `gdal.Translate`. I ended up using `gdal.Warp` as a small [intermediate step](https://gist.github.com/zeppehpt1/3d5bdfae18d868ce297c393dc6bd8d81) before producing the .tif output. The good thing is that the warping operation on the .vrt file is fast.

So maybe in your case you could try out adding:

```py
outds = gdal.BuildVRT(outvrt, file_list,xRes=10,yRes=10,separate=True)
final_outds = gdal.Warp(outvrt, outds, dstSRS='EPSG:32633')
final_outds = gdal.Translate(save_path, final_outds, format = "GTiff", creationOptions['TILED:YES'])
final_outds = None
```